# Displaying two records per page MVC using a page break CSS

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am returning a list in a MVC page. The list can have many records. I only want to show two records per page from the list. I am displaying information on certain parts of the pages using CSS. 
If there are 6 records then 3 pages and if there are 4 records then 2 pages. 
 I am not able to figure out how to use a Page break after every two records or is there a better way of doing it. I also tried to use the MOD function but was unsuccessful. I also tried to break the records in 2 by using the Group by function.

```
  @model List<SomeData>

#content {
    font: 1.5em Arial;
}
.address_top {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top: 0px;
    left: 40px;
}

.address_bottom {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top: 500px;
    left: 20px;
}


.RentTop {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top: 350px;
    left: 20px;
}

.RentBottom {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top: 400px;
    left: 20px;
}


.pagebreak {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

```
    <div id="content">
       @if (Model.Count() > 0)
         {

    for (var i = 1; i <= Model.Count; i++)
    {
        var items = Model[i - 1];
        var i1 = i;
        if (i1 % 2 == 0)
        {
            <div style="page-break-after:@(i1 % 2 == 0 ? "always" : "")">

                <div class="address_top">

                   500 south light street<BR />
                    P.O BOX 8444<BR />
                    boise, ID 45874<BR />
                    415 - 457 -7878
                </div>

                @*if (items.RentID == null || items.RentID == 0.ToString() || items.RentID == "")
                    {
                        <div class="RentTop">
                            @items.RentNumber
                        </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class=RentTop">
                            @items.DepositNumber
                        </div>
                    }*@
            </div>
        }

        else

        {
                <div class="address_bottom">
                500 south light street<BR />
                    P.O BOX 8444<BR />
                    boise, ID 45874<BR />
                    415 - 457 -7878
            </div>

                @*if (items.RentID == null || items.RentID == 0.ToString() || items.RentID == "")
                    {
                        <div class="RentBottom">
                            @items.RentNumber
                        </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="RentBottom">
                            @items.DepositNumber
                        </div>
                    }*@

        }

    }
}
```

```
     **Other Way I tried to do.**

      @{
      var batches = Model
    .Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
    .GroupBy(p => (p.i / 2), p => p.x);
     }
    @foreach (var row in batches)
        {
        <span>Row @row.Key</span>

   foreach (var item in row)
    {

     <div class="address_top">


              500 south light street<BR />
                    P.O BOX 8444<BR />
                    boise, ID 45874<BR />
                    415 - 457 -7878

</div>
    <div class="RentTop">
        @item.DepositNumber
    </div>

    }
 }
```

Comment: page-break-after has been replaced by break-after: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after and I think it only works when printing

Comment: Yes, page breaks only apply to printing. On a web page, there's no such thing as a "break". It just runs vertically as long as the document is.

Comment: k thanks for the page break(printing) but how can i show 2 records per page then. i thought that after showing two records i can do a page break and the the other two records will automatically go on the other page.

Comment: Is your list of objects being shown in a table on the view?

Comment: Possibly [this](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)?